# Force access to backing field of type T via property

Tags: c#, .net

Assume the following:

```
public class A<T>
{
    private T _field;
    public T Field {
      get{
             Console.WriteLine("hello");
             return _field;
         }
    }
}
```

Assume we instantiate A with some type T (disregard the missing constructor).

```
var myA = new A<Interface>();

var myField = myA.Field; // This will print "hello"
myA.Field.SomeOperationThatExistsOnInterface(); // So will this

myField.SomeOperationThatExistsOnInterface(); // I would like this to also print "hello" somehow
```

I.e. I would like to force access to a backing field via the property accessor. Any magic to accomplish this?
Also acceptable would be to prevent assignment from the property and restrict access via myA.Field.[...].

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve this as long as `A<T>` exposes the `T` instance. In theory `A<T>` could do IL rewriting on `T` and inject the IL instructions for `Console.WriteLine("hello");` to the start of `T.SomeOperationThatExistsOnInterface()`, but that'll be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use closure but usage will be clunky

```cs
var myField = new Action(() => myA.Field);
var b = myField.Invoke().SomeOperationThatExistsOnInterface();
```

Comment: There's still no way to force the caller to do that. How is this better than just using `myA.Field.SomeOperationThatExistsOnInterface()`?

Comment: @41686d6564 it's extremely weird use case to force users to **don't store into variable**. It's bad design if users had to work this way. A bit of knowledge of how assignment works would let you know that such thing is impossible in CLR as in any runtime that I know (C/C++, dotnet, python)

Comment: Well, _that_ should be the answer then (or maybe a comment). But saying "here's another thing you can't force the caller to do" is not really an answer to the "how do I force the caller to do X?" question. At least that's my opinion.